# change a fixed html code to a responsive format

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I write this code for static content...now how can I change it to support mobile device (responsive format)
[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/jq3y3oab/1/)

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;      
    border:1px solid red;
}

.box1{
    width:100px;
    height:90px;      
    border:1px solid yellow;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
}

.box2{
    width:80px;
    height:25px;      
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px;
}
```

I want all box be resize with exchange resolation...(location of boxes are fixed)

Comment: add `.box` `margin:0 auto` so that it stays in the center of the screen because your `.box` width is `200px` and minimum mobile device width is `320px` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq3y3oab/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add max-width for the box classes. This will resize the boxes according to the resolution.

```
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;      
    border:1px solid red;
    max-width:100%;
}

.box1{
    width:100px;
    height:90px;      
    border:1px solid yellow;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
    max-width:40%;
}

.box2{
    width:80px;
    height:25px;      
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px;
    max-width:40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'exchange resolation' but looking at your layout, i would first change the fixed widths to % values. That itself will make them fluid as you shrink your browser window.

For mobile devices, write a media query for targeting small widths and remove the float property in the media query and set their width to 100%. so all boxes are displayed one below another.

usually, i prefer using inline-block over float property. It gives more flexibility in styling. 
just my 2 cents.